# NEO4J shortestPath taking into account a particular relationship pattern

Tags: neo4j, relationship, shortest-path

I have a graph where I have chains of nodes that have a relationship [:LINKS_TO] and I can successfully get the shortestPath function to work.

For most of my users this level of detail is fine.

I have another set of users where there is a need for a richer set of information on the relationship.  Given that properties on relationships are supposed to represent strengths or scores for the relationship I have created specific nodes to hold descriptive metadata.

This means I have a pattern that says (start)-[:PARTICIPATES]-(middle)-[:REFERENCES]->(end)

There can be any number of nodes between the start and end points in the chain.

I am struggling to get the shortestPath function to return any results for the more detailed chain.  Is there a way to do this using Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have kept your metadata information on the relationships.

For your needs, this should work:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((start)-[:PARTICIPATES|:REFERENCES*]->(end))
RETURN nodes(p)
```

Comment: I had to tweak this slightly to the following
`//Shortest DB relationship path
MATCH (startTable { name:"ProductPhoto" }),(endTable { name:"Customer" }),
  p = shortestPath((startTable)-[r:PARTICIPATES_IN|:REFERENCES*..15]-(endTable))
RETURN p`